# Java: How to draw & put text on a bitmap (for low-res sign)

Tags: java, bitmap, draw

I recently aquired a 112x16 pixel Flip-Dot sign and I want to put cool stuff on it. (Think current temp, playlist items etc.)

The sign has two modes, a rather limited text mode and a bitmap mode.
I know how to put text or a bitmap on the sign, what I'm looking for is tips how to put texts, sprites and simple things like a line on a bitmap that I can then put on the sign.
For example: If I want to show a progress bar of my current playing Item, I would want to draw a few lines/rectangles showing the progress bar, and some text with current and total time above it.

I'm not looking for specific code, but what libraries/projects you would use.
At first glance a BufferedImage looks right to hold the image, but can't find a lot on how to draw on it.

Also, looking for specific tips on low-res bitmap fonts.

I could find a lot on how to draw on the android-specific Canvas, which isn't helping, since this will be something that runs on a raspberry Pi.